# Why entity framework not inserting data to .mdf file?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application

I am using **console application** to insert data into .mdf file which is in App_Data folder and .edmx file in project folder.

The same below code is working with mvc but not console application.

Table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbLegalDetails] (
[LegalStatusId]           INT            NOT NULL,
[LegalStatusName]         TEXT           NULL,
[LegalStatusHeading]      TEXT           NULL,
[PatentOfInvention]       NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[EventCode]               VARCHAR (100)  NULL,
[EventExplination]        TEXT           NULL,
[CCOfCorrespondingPatent] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[CorrespondingPatentD]    INT            NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LegalStatusId] ASC)
);
```

Code to insert data is:

```
ConsoleApplication__DynamicWebBrowserDatabaseEntities db = new ConsoleApplication__DynamicWebBrowserDatabaseEntities();
List<tbLegalDetail> hLegalDetaili = db.tbLegalDetails.ToList();

[Here count is shown as 0]

tbLegalDetail tbLegalDetail = new tbLegalDetail();
tbLegalDetail.LegalStatusId = 3;
tbLegalDetail.LegalStatusName = "INPADOC legal";
tbLegalDetail.LegalStatusHeading = "COMPOSITIONS ANDAPY";
tbLegalDetail.PatentOfInvention = "2003287377";
tbLegalDetail.EventCode = "FGA";
tbLegalDetail.EventExplination = "LETTSTANDARD PATENT";
tbLegalDetail.CCOfCorrespondingPatent = "dfs";
tbLegalDetail.CorrespondingPatentD = 1212;
db.tbLegalDetails.Add(tbLegalDetail);
db.SaveChanges();
List<tbLegalDetail> hLegalDetail = db.tbLegalDetails.ToList();

[Here count is shown as 1]

Console.ReadLine();
```

but when I look into the .mdf file I cant see the added row.
When I run again I will show count as 0.

Please help.

Comment: Any errors thrown? If EF6, take a look at the generated SQL, use this before inserting and look to debug console: db.Database.Log = Console.Write;

Comment: No no errors or exceptions thrown. The only difference is it says When I try to create .edmx file it says "The connection you selected uses a local data file that is not in the current project.Do you want to copy it to project." which I don't get in MVC though .mdf file is in App_Data folder.

Comment: Usual reasons for this is that you are copying the mdf to the output folder when you build your project and it is using this copy.

Comment: I can see .pdb file in debug folder.

Comment: Can any one try to run the code. May be you can find the problem.

Comment: mdf file is bin\Debug\App_Data and .pdb file is in bin\Debug\

Comment: Yes I think he is right when I compared to mvc application there is no mdf file created in bin folder. Console application is creating a new mdf file in bin folder and using it instead of the main .mdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this question form the comments given by @sgmoore and @vipin.

I changed the **|DataDirectory| in the connection string in App.config file to full path** which solved the problem

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Console application or windows form application uses resource from debug folder(A copy). May you got your changes from the .mdf file presented in your debug folder (Just after the run / Before the second run).

May this article talks you more.. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/663453/Understanding-Clean-Build-and-Rebuild-in-Visual-St